# How to ignore white spaces in a string using Regex in php

Tags: php, regex

```
I have a string = "[VIDEO]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etye3skwu9w[/Video]"
```

I am using the following Regex to match VIDEO tags

```
'/\[VIDEO\](.+?)\[\/VIDEO\]/i'
```

It works fine if there is no space in `[VIDEO]` tag. But if there is any space like `[ VIDEO ],` it will not work.

How can I ignore spaces. I mean if the Tag is like this `[ VIDEO ]`, my REGEX Should Work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `\s*` at the positions where you want to allow whitespace. `\s` is whitespace, `*` is any number of repetitions (including zero):

```
'/\[\s*VIDEO\s*\](.+?)\[\s*\/VIDEO\s*\]/i
```

Answer (score 1):

`\s` matches any whitespace. You could use this:

```
'/\[\s*VIDEO\s*\](.+?)\[\s*\/\s*VIDEO\s*\]/i'
```

This allows whitespaces like `[ VIDEO ]` or `[/ VIDEO]`. Or, to allow just spaces

```
'/\[ *VIDEO *\](.+?)\[ *\/ *VIDEO *\]/i'
```

or *one* space

```
'/\[ ?VIDEO ?\](.+?)\[ ?\/ ?VIDEO ?\]/i'
```